# Character length in a field

Tags: count, crystal-reports, character

I can find answers to other very similar questions but cannot seem to find answers to my issue. I have a field that the correct returns would be something like 'L12-012345' Character count before and after the '-' is constant. I am trying to get my report to simply return with any outcome that is not formatted like this, meaning if there was a space anywhere in there, if the character count before the '-' does not start with 'L' and 2 digits, if the '-' is missing totally, if there are not exactly 6 digits after the '-'. Some I've come across has 18 digits after the '-', others I have found 1 digit after the '-'. Any assistance would really be appreciated. If it matters, I am working with Crystal Reports, and my report does use a parameter field. I've looked for length, trim, Right, Left formulas. I've looked for Select expert with the parameters....

No version of what I have tried (see above) works. I feel that this needs to be under Select Expert, but I'm lost as to what formula would return this information!

Answer (score 0):

A good strategy would be to start with a couple of simple filter criteria in the record selection formula, such as

```
LEN({your_column}) <> 10
OR 
UBound(Split({your_column}, "-")) <> 2
```

Note that you must use OR rather than AND (perhaps that was your problem).

If this yields correct results, gradually add more conditions.
If this doesn't yield correct results, you have a simple-enough start to investigate.

Comment: Oh goodness, I was right there! Thank you so much!